# How to reload the ssh config file in Mac OS X via terminal

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, terminal

When I update my ssh config file so I can switch my current github account, the changes wont work properly unless I restart iTerm. I'm working on a script to automate the github account switch and I'd like to have the script reload the config settings in the updated config file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How, do you switch accounts? Do you use `ssh-agent`? The `ssh_config` is read for every single invocation of `ssh`.

Comment: Can you give us more detail about the config file? Also, could you define different hosts for the different github accounts, and avoid the reloading problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In my case, I finally discovered that the issue wasn't the config file (`ssh -vvv -F /dev/null -i /some/path/some_other_key` and even moving the old keys in `~/.ssh/` elsewhere, nonetheless still managed to magick the old key out of nowhere), but rather the `ssh agent`.  I had to clear it with `ssh-add -D`.

`man ssh_config` clarifies that `-i` on `ssh` should take precedence over the `~/.ssh/config` file; so if you're doing this and it's still not working, some undocumented higher priority power is butting in.

Comment: `ssh-add -D` did the trick

Comment: that's it! - I've been looking for why my changes never reflected...  `ssh-add -D` refreshed it.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to look at the [Atlassian documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html) on using multiple identities. A case like the one I think you're describing - switching accounts - may be best handled with an SSH config file that accommodates multiple accounts simultaneously instead of scripting.

They provide the following example for the `config` file at ~/.ssh/config:

```
# Default GitHub user
Host github.com
 HostName github.com
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid

# Work user account
Host bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid
```

Comment: Note you could also use different `Host` nicknames for the same `HostName`, with different `IdentityFile`s for each: `Host github-charlie`, `Host github-sam`

Answer (score 0):

While I was looking for a way to 'refresh' the file I realised what I was actually looking for was a way to auto complete the command,

Refreshing was not necessary as @Jakuje above mentions

For those interested the auto complete script is:

```
complete -o default -o nospace -W "$(grep "^Host" $HOME/.ssh/config | cut -d" " -f2)" scp sftp ssh
```

Which I found [here](http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/05/setup-ssh-config-fie/).

Add the above script to `.bash_profile` and then run `source .bash_profile`